# Async programming in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to get my head around asynchronous programming in C#. I've created a basic WPF program. This includes a new class `CleaningService` that has an async `Start()` method. The WPF program has a button that calls the `Start()` method on click.

Within this `Start()` method, I want to call an async `Method1()` method and then an async `Method2()` method.

When I click on the button, `Method2()` doesn't get called. Why would this be the case?

Code:

```
class CleaningService : ICleaningService
{
    private bool _continue;

    public async void Start()
    {
        this._continue = true;

        if (!await this.Method1())
        {
            this._continue = false;
        }

        if (!await this.Method2())
        {
            this._continue = false;
        }
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        this._continue = false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Method1()
    {
        // do something
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Method1..");
        return await new Task<bool>(() => true);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Method2()
    {
        if (this._continue)
        {
            // do something
            Console.WriteLine("Processing Method2..");
            return await new Task<bool>(() => true);
        }
        else
        {
            return await new Task<bool>(() => false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never use the task constructor. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

You never started the task in `Method1` (you just created a `Task`, but it was never started)

Comment: Ah thanks. I guess I should just do something like Thread.Sleep(1); instead.

Comment: You can do use `Task.Run(...)`